# SQL Server max value retrieve

Tags: sql-server

I have the following 3 tables in database1

```
create table database1..Table1 (id int ,datestamp datetime)
create table database1..Table2 (id int ,datestamp datetime)
create table database1..Table3(id int ,datestamp datetime)
```

and this table in database2

```
create table database2..Table1 (id int ,datestamp datetime)
```

I want to update Table1 .datestamp of the database2 by the bigger value of datestamp (between the 3 tables of the database1)

Is there a better way than this query (without using case):

```
update db2t1
set datestamp=
case    when db1t1.datestamp > db1t2.datestamp and db1t1.datestamp > db1t3.datestamp then db1t1.datestamp
        when db1t2.datestamp > db1t1.datestamp and db1t2.datestamp > db1t3.datestamp then db1t2.datestamp
        else db1t3.datestamp
    end
from database2..Table1 db2t1 inner join database1..Table1 db1t1 on db2t1.id=db1t1.id
inner join database1..Table2 db1t2 on db1t1.id=db1t2.id
inner join database1..Table3 db1t3 on db1t1.id=db1t2.id
```

This query will be executed on a huge tables

Comment: In the case where `db1t1.datestamp` and `db1t2.datestamp` are equal, you'll be setting the value to `db1t3.datestamp` even if it's lower than the other two.

Comment: That's pretty much how you'd do it (bearing in mind what TZHX said, and that you might be able to save a little effort if you're setting the value to itself). If these tables are keyed on id, you'd be hard pressed for the size of the data to make much of a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do something like this:

```
UPDATE db2t1
SET db2t1.datestamp = tbl2.MaxDate
from database2..Table1 db2t1
JOIN
(
    SELECT
        MAX(tbl.datestamp) AS MaxDate,
        tbl.id
    FROM
    (
        SELECT id,datestamp database1..Table1 UNION ALL
        SELECT id,datestamp database1..Table2 UNION ALL
        SELECT id,datestamp database1..Table3
    ) AS tbl
    GROUP BY
       tbl.id
) AS tbl2
ON tbl2.id=db2t1.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Any way you do this on big tables is going to be difficult. I would split this into batches (based on ranges of the ID assuming it is clustered key) and change the query to be like this:

```
UPDATE T1
SET dateStamp = X.dateStamp
FROM database2..Table1 T1
JOIN (SELECT ID, MAX(dateStamp) dateStamp
    FROM (
            SELECT ID, dateStamp
            FROM table2 T2
            UNION ALL
            SELECT ID, dateStamp
            FROM table3 T3
         ) N
    GROUP BY ID) X ON X.ID = T1.ID
WHERE X.dateStamp > T1.dateStamp
```

To reduce the time that T1 is locked you could put the derived table into a temp table and then update T1 from the results.